# can I use git clone between my pc and shared server (with ssh access)?

Tags: git

if 
I have PC A (my laptop) which I use program on it and push and pull from my bitbucket repo.
AND 
I have PC B (my server) which I push and pull from my bitbucket repo. to publish my code

Question: Can I push and pull using PC A(my laptop) From PC B(my server) ?


I tried to clone using ssh from my PC A 
this is the response
fatal: 'my path' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Google `git daemon` and you could find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

that simple answer is yes I can.
I have been using an incorrect path as it was shared host the right url were different.